# Node Editor Material Transparency Problem

Tags: materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I've set up a material in the node editor that basically makes the mesh that it is applied to look act as if backface culling was turned on.
However my problem with this is that the Transparency setting is no longer effective, as is illustrated in the screenshot below. Although Transparency is only set to about 50 percent, the resulting material is still entirely opaque because of the node setup (which I got from a thread on this site and do not really understand tbh)

So my question is if anyone knows how I can set up the material as to allow me to influence and animate its transparency while retaining the 'quasi-backface culling' node setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers folks!

[image: transparency Alpha does not affect the output's transparency]

Comment: use a math node to sum the alpha out and the front/back out ,  and feed it to the output node

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get that to work. Have you tried this yourself? Maybe you could elaborate, might be that I'm missing something?

Comment: sorry the sum didn't do it but see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a math node and set it to Minimum and plug the Alpha output and the Front/Back output to it then connect the result to the Alpha input of the Output node. this way the the back faces will be totally transparent and the front faces will have the alpha you set in the material tab.

[image]